# Implement Deposit Method in PHP with Interfaces

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to implement this deposit method in PHP OOP but I don't understand why I can't return the amount plus that balance.

Here is my code:

index.php

```
//load all interfaces in interfaces folder
foreach (glob('interfaces/*.php') as $filename)
{
    require_once $filename;
}
//load all classes in classes folder
foreach (glob('classes/*.php') as $filename)
{
    require_once $filename;
}


function test($cond, $desc)
{
    if ($cond) {
        echo '<span style="color:green">Passed</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:red">Failed</span>';
    }

    echo ' - ' . $desc;

    echo '<br><hr><br>';
}


/*------ Tests --------*/

//set opening balances
$myBankAccount = new BankAccount(new Money(1200));
$yourBankAccount = new BankAccount(new Money(500));

test((int) (string) $myBankAccount->balance() == 1200, "Opening balance remains the same");
test((int) (string) $yourBankAccount->balance() == 500, "Opening balance remains the same");

//deposit money into account
$myBankAccount->deposit(new Money(300));
test((int) (string) $myBankAccount->balance() == 1500, "Deposit increases the balance");


$myBankAccount->deposit(new Money(300));
test((int) (string) $myBankAccount->balance() == 1500, "Deposit increases the balance");



//withdraw money from account
$yourBankAccount->withdraw(new Money(300));
test((int) (string) $yourBankAccount->balance() == 200, "withdrawl decreases the balance");

//transfer money between accounts
$myBankAccount->transfer(new Money(1000), $yourBankAccount);
test((int) (string) $myBankAccount->balance() == 500, "Transfer decreases balance from target account");
test((int) (string) $yourBankAccount->balance() == 1200, "Transfer increases balance on destination account");


//withdraw too much
try {
    $myBankAccount->withdraw(new Money(600));
    test(true == false, "Did not throw exception when withdrawing more than balance");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    test($ex->getMessage() == 'Withdrawl amount larger than balance', "throws exception when too much money is withdrawn");
}

//transfer too much
try {
    $myBankAccount->transfer(new Money(1000), $yourBankAccount);
    test(true == false, "Did not throw exception when transferring more than balance");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    test($ex->getMessage() == 'Withdrawl amount larger than balance', "throws exception when too much money is transferred");
    test((int) (string) $myBankAccount->balance() == 500, "Target account balance remains same after failed transfer");
    test((int) (string) $yourBankAccount->balance() == 1200, "Destination account balance remains same after failed transfer");
}
```

BankAccount.php

```
class BankAccount implements IfaceBankAccount
{

    private $balance = null;

    public function __construct(Money $openingBalance)
    {
        $this->balance = $openingBalance;
    }

    public function balance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }

    public function deposit(Money $amount)
    {
        // implement this method
    }

    public function withdraw(Money $amount)
    {
        $this->balance - $amount;
    }

    public function transfer(Money $amount, BankAccount $account)
    {
        // implement this method
    }
}
```

I need to make the deposit method work but it doesn't seem to add the amount and balance together when I try:

```
public function deposit(Money $amount)
    {
        return $this->balance + $amount;
    }
```

The Money class has a private amount property. Any idea what I need to do? Or should I share the other classes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `$amount` is instance (object) of class `Money`. If you need property of an object - is it `$amount->amount`.

Comment: I tried this return $this->balance() + $amount->amount; but it didnt work.

Comment: What `private` means?

Comment: @u_mulder well the Money class has a value() method which returns the amount. This returns the right number but the code still fails: return $this->balance->value() + $amount->value();

Answer (score 0):

I see the two possible solutions here.

**First**, if you have a really dumb class `Money`:

```
class Money
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        // Here might be some business rules regarding validation of amount
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Then your `BankAccount` class will look like this:

```
class BankAccount implements IfaceBankAccount
{

    private $balance = null;

    public function __construct(Money $openingBalance)
    {
        $this->balance = $openingBalance->getAmount();
    }

    public function getBalance()
    {
        // This might be bottleneck during unit testing, because you cannot
        // mock this one.
        return new Money($this->balance);
    }

    public function deposit(Money $money)
    {
        $this->balance += $money->getAmount();

        return $this;
    }

    public function withdraw(Money $money)
    {
        // Here might be some business rules regarding negative balance.
        $this->balance -= $money->getAmount();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So your problem with your methods was that they have not changed the private property `$balance`. The `deposit` method only returned the new balance. And the `withdraw` method actually did nothing.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1036c457a4cf63f1a52b9c448cf367190bcce4e3).

**Second**, if you have smarter class `Money` with `increase` and `decrease` methods in it:

```
class Money
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        // Here might be some business rules regarding validation of amount
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function increase($amount)
    {
        $this->amount += $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function decrease($amount)
    {
        $this->amount -= $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Then `BankAccount` class will look like this:

```
class BankAccount implements IfaceBankAccount
{

    private $balance = null;

    public function __construct(Money $openingBalance)
    {
        $this->balance = $openingBalance;
    }

    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }

    public function deposit(Money $money)
    {
        $this->balance->increase($money->getAmount());

        return $this;
    }

    public function withdraw(Money $money)
    {
        // Here might be some business rules regarding negative balance.
        $this->balance->decrease($money->getAmount());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/845ff019d5b95b69ed55ecae42b0567843f01b48).

I prefer the second one because it saves you from recreating `Money` instances over and over again (for example when you use `getBalance` method). You can go even further and implement `decrease` and `increase` methods to accept `Money` instances also. For the sake of simplicity, I have not done it.

**The main point to make here is that your `BankAccount` class is the API to make changes to the `$balance`. So `deposit` and `withdraw` methods should actually change `$balance`.** They should not return new balance. For this, you have method `getBalance`. **Methods should be as small as possible (but not smaller) and do one and only one thing**.

You can read [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section of PHP documentation to take a grasp of OOP in PHP. But I am not sure it will give you advice on style or design. For this, you need to read some books. For example, take a look at a book called *"Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin ("Uncle Bob")*. Although the examples are in JAVA, but the concepts are applicable to OOP and OOD in general.